# How to rename a view in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have created  a view `vw_extr`.

Now I want to rename it `vw_my`.

How can a view be renamed in MySQL?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use `RENAME TABLE` for that:

```
RENAME TABLE vw_extr to vw_my
```

Comment: If it's within the same database, it's OK, but contrary to tables, MySQL does not support moving views from one database to another. Thus, DROP+CREATE is a more general approach.

Comment: Good point. Trying to rename a view to move it from one schema to another will give this error: `ERROR 1450 (HY000): Changing schema from '<old>' to '<new>' is not allowed.`

Answer (score 1):

`DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vw_extr;`

`CREATE VIEW vw_my ...`

You'll have to fill my `...` with your view's DDL.

Comment: I did not get the ... part, Please elaborate

Comment: It's...what you used to create vw_extr in the first place

Comment: It's a lot easier to just use `RENAME TABLE`

Comment: @Ike Will `RENAME TABLE` work for views (I've never tried it)? If so, then I agree it is easier.

Comment: Rename table does work with views. Thanks for the information people :)

Answer (score 1):

Rename didn't work for me, what I did was:

Stop MySQL, change to my database directory, and rename from `my_old_view.frm` to `my_new_view.frm`.

I was using linux, so the commands were:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
cd /var/lib/mysq/DatabaseName
mv my_old_view.frm my_new_view.frm
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Answer (score -1):

View doesn't provide options to rename it like table as its a virtual table.
MS SQL Server recompile when ever we create alter. Please refer attached URL.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-ver15